# ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column on Nifi PutDatabaseRecord

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

I try to update some DB column in Oracle Database with Nifi.

I have such part of the circuit:

[image: Map]

I have problem with last `PutDatabaserecord`:

```
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-12 17:34:20,919 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord PutDatabaseRecord[id=017a10b4-fe2c-1b89-f752-67545ebb8406] Failed to put Records to database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=db4a0554-6ea8-4cca-b1da-11bdacef1ccc,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1625839380170-6543, container=default, section=399], offset=292967, length=68],offset=0,name=f4d1875f-bec4-4944-ad8e-7955048148f3,size=68]. Routing to failure.: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    | 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    | java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    | 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10032)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1364)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9839)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:234)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:242)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:242)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.access$100(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:38)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler$ProxiedReturnObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:240)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.executeDML(PutDatabaseRecord.java:754)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.putToDatabase(PutDatabaseRecord.java:841)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.onTrigger(PutDatabaseRecord.java:487)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1173)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:214)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
nifi_ml_nifi.1.rb4f8g690fro@KoshDomain    |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is configuration of the problematic node:

[image: Configuration]

[image: Configuration_next]

This is a schema of RecordReader:

```
{
    "name": "load_date",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "maxi",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "doc_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "line_id",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "load_date",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this is a sample of the json data coming to the node:

```
[{"doc_id":1795576199,"line_id":689617855,"load_date":"2021-34-12"}]
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I set PutDatabaseRecord to Debug mode, evaluated sigle record? for catch full debug info from the processor. This is the head of the log exactly as the processor starts to handle the record:

```
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-13 14:15:23,951 INFO [NiFi Web Server-456] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting SplitJson[id=9f810155-017a-1000-890c-4b1e382a161e]
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-13 14:15:23,951 INFO [NiFi Web Server-456] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting SplitJson[id=9f810155-017a-1000-890c-4b1e382a161e]
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-13 14:15:23,964 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled SplitJson[id=9f810155-017a-1000-890c-4b1e382a161e] to run with 1 threads
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-13 14:15:23,976 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord PutDatabaseRecord[id=017a10b4-fe2c-1b89-f752-67545ebb8406] Failed to put Records to database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9c53fd8b-775b-42a6-bcae-fb4208a40985,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1626174735665-61, container=default, section=61], offset=776075, length=330],offset=0,name=51510f97-7a54-4394-966a-12775653acb0,size=66]. Routing to failure.: java.sql.SQLDataException: Cannot map field 'doc_id' to any column in the database
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | Columns: 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | java.sql.SQLDataException: Cannot map field 'doc_id' to any column in the database
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | Columns: 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.generateUpdate(PutDatabaseRecord.java:1073)
```

(I added one another processor there - `SplitJson`)

And, I added some table in my own scheme on the DB.

This is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE psheom.ml_task (
  doc_id number, 
  line_id number,
  load_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT pk_ml_task PRIMARY KEY(doc_id, line_id) 
)
```

And this is result of `DESCRIBE psheom.ml_task`:

```
Name      Null?    Type   
--------- -------- ------ 
DOC_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER 
LINE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER 
LOAD_DATE          DATE
```

**UPDATE**

I try to make ExecuteSql processor as @pmdba suggests, but I get some error. Here is configuration:

[image: desc table]

And here is error:

```
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 2021-07-13 14:57:19,137 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL ExecuteSQL[id=9fb97e49-017a-1000-bae9-256f569c239b] Unable to execute SQL select query describe psheom.ml_task due to java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | . No FlowFile to route to failure: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    | 
nifi_ml_nifi.1.zutify8jh9sv@KoshDomain    |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
```

**UPDATE**

I set `Translate Field Names` to `false`, but it is same result.

Comment: What is the definition (DDL) of the good.ml_task table? Do you have any way to capture the actual SQL statement that was submitted?

Comment: I can not to capture SQL statements, and I have no access to the DDL of the table.

Comment: The content of the failed flow files should tell you which values where submitted, and you can use an ExecuteSQL processor to run `describe good.ml_task` and capture the output.

Comment: See updates please.

Comment: Try setting "Translate Field Names" to "false".

Comment: Yes, it is false now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it is quite a "few things" that we need to do for `UPDATE` some record in `Oracle`.

First of all **DO NOT** use DBeaver! It is very glitchy! Use just SQLDeveloper for working with Oracle.

Second, create session with same user configured for connection pool in Nifi side, and run `DESCRIBE` for table you need to update:

```
DESCRIBE GOODS.ML_TASK
```

Be sure, it succeeds!

Third, we need upper case all entity names, and it is good to set `Translate Field Names` to `false`, thus it removes underscores, ie.: `doc_id -> docid`.

[image: Processor's config]

Firth, you need `json` with upper case field names in the processor's input:

```
[
  {"DOC_ID":1799041400,"LINE_ID":694098344,"LOAD_DATE":"14-Jul-21"},
  {"DOC_ID":1802019315,"LINE_ID":697885808,"LOAD_DATE":"14-Jul-21"}
]
```

If you have lower case field in some place, use `UpdateAttribute` processor with reader and writer where reader will upper case the fields:

[image: Uppercase json fields]

The schema defined for PutDatabaseRecord reader **MUST** be upper cased:

```
{
    "name": "load_date",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "maxi",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "DOC_ID",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "LINE_ID",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "LOAD_DATE",
        "type": "string"
      }
   ]
}
```

So here you have:

`UpdateRecord`:

1. IncomingJsonReader for accept record in lower case, and make uppercase
2. IncomingJsonWriter

`PutDatanaseRecord`

1. OutgoingJsonReader

All of them use **THE SAME JSON SCHEMA**

Fifth, as you seen, use `string` type for date.

You can put date as number of milliseconds sine THE DATE, but, despite the fact it worked in my own schema, it didn't worked in the production schema. So you need to query `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Put the appropriate query in `ExecuteSQL` processor:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

[image: Query Date format]

You will have the format in the result queue:

```
[{"PARAMETER": "NLS_DATE_FORMAT", "VALUE": "DD-MON-RR"}]
```

Use it for make date formatted in the appropriate way.

Sixth, as we see, put the right date format in the "Expression Language" expression in the right place, for instance, in `UpdateRecord` in my case:

[image: UpdateRecord]

Seventh, make sure you have just single or few records passing threw the queues, for be able to monitor the log. Also put the `PutDatabaseRecord` in `DEBUG` mode:

[image: Debug mode]

In such a way, it will inform you, whether it succeed to fetch the schema from DB.

So... I wish you happy Oracle's table update!